# Stripe invalid request - using a token more than once

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Code:

```
Stripe::setApiKey($stripe_secret_key);
Stripe::setApiVersion('2017-02-14');



// Either create a new customer object or retrieve the existing customer object

$db->query(" SELECT StripeCustomerToken FROM stripe_ids WHERE UPPER(UserEmail) = UPPER(:email) ");
$db->bind(':email', $user_email);
$db->execute();
$customer_token = $db->fetchSingleColumn();

if(!$customer_token)
{
    $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(
        [
            'card' => $stripe_card_token,
            'description' => $user_email,
            'email'=>$user_email
        ],
        $stripe_access_token
    );

    $customer_token = $customer->id;

    $db->query(" INSERT INTO stripe_ids (UserEmail, StripeCustomerToken) VALUES (:e, :custID) ");
    $db->bind(':e', $user_email);
    $db->bind(':custID', $customer_token);
    $db->execute();
}

if(!$customer_token)
    throw new Exception('No Stripe Customer Token detected. The payment could not be processed.');

$customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($customer_token);



// Using the token ID, retrieve the full token object and retrieve the fingerprint from the `card.fingerprint` attribute

$current_card = Stripe_Token::retrieve($stripe_card_token);
$current_card_fingerprint = $current_card->card->fingerprint;
$current_card_id = $current_card->card->id;



// Iterate through the list of the customer's saved sources and check if any has the same value for its `fingerprint`

$source_exists = false;
foreach($customer->sources->data as $i => $fingerprint)
{
    if($current_card_fingerprint === $fingerprint)
        $source_exists = true;
}



// If not, add the card to the customer object

if(!$source_exists)
    $customer->sources->create(['source' => $stripe_card_token]);

$customer->default_source = $current_card_id;
$customer->save();



// Create the charge using the customer ID and the card ID

$charge = [
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'source' => $current_card_id,
    'amount' => $total_gross_received_cents,
    'currency' => 'EUR',
    'description' => $transaction_description_str,
    'application_fee' => $databiz_fee
];

$charge_obj = Stripe_Charge::create($charge, $stripe_access_token);

if(empty($charge_obj))
    throw new Exception('No Stripe Charge Object detected. The payment could not be processed.');

$charge_token = $charge_obj->id;
```

Issue:

Each time a customer uses the application, they must enter their CC details. Therefore I want to:

1. Create the customer, if they do not already exist
2. Check if they have the current card as a source and, if not, add it as a source
3. Charge the currently used card

I was running into trouble whereby a returning customer's default card was not being updated to the currently used card (resulting in the funds coming from the default), so I added the card ID to the charge object, and saved the current card as the customer's default.

The issue now is that, on a live transaction, I am getting an InvalidRequest exception - I cannot use a token more than once.

Can someone point out to me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token you're providing when adding the card to the customer (with `$customer->sources->create(...)`) has likely already been consumed by another API request. You should check your integration to ensure that `$stripe_card_token` contains a "fresh" token created by [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements).

A few other things that I noticed:

- you're using [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) with [direct charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges). This means the customer objects must exist on the connected account, not on the platform's account. When you retrieve the customer, you don't specify the connected account's API key, so the request is issued on your platform's account and will fail (since the customer ID doesn't exist on the platform's account)
- you're using an old version (1.x) of [Stripe's PHP library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#stripe-php-bindings). You should consider upgrading to a more recent version. This will require updating your code to the new syntax (`Stripe_Class` -> `\Stripe\Class`)
- when looking if the card already exists on the customer, you iterate over `$customer->sources->data`. Note that when retrieving the customer object, this attribute will contain at most 10 sources. If the customer has more than 10 sources, you will need to use [pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pagination) to retrieve the full list.

  Note that if you use a recent version of the Stripe's PHP library, you can use the [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#auto-pagination) feature to handle this easily.

Comment: The `$stripe_card_token` is not otherwise used (to my understanding) - I'm using Stripe's JS library to retrieve it, and then it directly fed to this processor. The API connection is made using the appropriate secret key for the connected account (it only exists for use by the platform).

Comment: Since you're retrieving the full token object in `$current_card`, can you output the value of `$current_card->used` to check if the token is used or not?

Comment: apologies for the delay! I outputted the value twice through the script to see if any changes were visible (once after I retrieved the card for its fingerprint and id, and once after I saved it as the default source). In both cases, the output was empty.

Comment: `used` is a boolean, so it will have a true or false value. Are you using e.g. `var_dump` to output its value?

Comment: I'm assigning a value 'used' / 'not_used' based on `$val = ($current_card->used)`. I'm outputting to a txt file and getting 'not_used' for both instances...

Comment: Weird. Can you confirm that the `\Stripe\InvalidRequestError` exception is raised when calling `$customer->sources->create(...)`?

Comment: As I recall, yes - on the live environment. I'll have to wait till later to do some more testing on that